# Check website for deprecated libraries and known CVEs

Tags: cve

I was curious if anyone knew of a tool, website, or browser extension that will tell you if a site has deprecated libraries and if there are CVEs related to that. I currently have burpsuite pro and ZAP as a tool. However, I am really looking for something that can tell us if our site is using the updated libraries.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: You need to scan the code, not the site. And there is a whole field of products that do open source version assessments. Look for "software composition analysis" and "open source audits".

Comment: Thank you @schroeder I found a burp suite extension and a cli tool that does this in our dev enviroment. cheers